# JavaScript - Dynamically generate a file path from an object

Tags: javascript, object, path

I've looked for hours and still I couldn't find anything about it so I'm asking here. I have a small PHP script which generates a JSON tree of files and folders, and then fetches it to client side as a JavaScript variable. The outcome usually looks like this:

```
{
  "folder_name" : {
    "another_folder": {
      "third_folder": {
        0: "some_file.txt"
        1: "another_file.png"
        2: "third_file.pdf"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm wanted to achive would look something like this:

```
generatePath("some_file.txt")
```

Which would return:

```
"folder_name/another_folder/third_folder/some_file.txt"
```

So my question is how can I create a path to any of those files just from an object in JavaScript? Is there even a way to do anything like this?

[Edit]: Sadly I don't have any code to show anymore...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't even know where the start with that, I've tried creating a recursive function that would read the key/value of an object and then glue it together. I think it was a good place to start but I failed with that. I've looked on the internet for just any tips or ideas but it seems like nobody ever needed anything like this. No tutorials, no information, simply nothing.

Comment: Can you share your failed effort? You've already proved you have an idea of what you want

Comment: Sadly I as a teenager after hours of fails I raged out and burned everything down... Now it's a day later. That's why I haven't shared any code.

Comment: This JSON is not valid. You can't have numbers as object properties and there are missing commas. So how does it really look like?

Comment: It looks exactly as I showed in the example. That object is generated by a PHP script and then fetched to JavaScript.

Comment: Unless you change it to valid JSON we're looking at some weird string parsing (regex maybe) first before we even start digging into where is the "file name" inside.

Comment: Look at it here https://pasteboard.co/IUoLNrs.png That's just some random files copied from my brothers computer, but It preatty much looks always this way. Interestingly enough it works on all major browsers I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming the input is a real JSON and it will parse into JS object here is some approach:

```js
const data = {
  "folder_name" : {
    "another_folder": {
      "third_folder": {
        "0": "some_file.txt",
        "1": "another_file.png",
        "2": "third_file.pdf"
      }
    }
  },
  "folder_name2" : {
    "0": "up_file.txt",
    "another_folder2": {
      "third_folder2": ["some_file2.txt", "another_file2.png", "third_file2.pdf"]
    }
  }
}

function generatePath(value, currentPath = '', currentObject = data) {
  for (const property in currentObject) {
    if (currentObject[property] === value) {
      return `${currentPath}/${value}`;
    }
    if (typeof currentObject[property] === 'object') {
      const result = generatePath(value, `${currentPath && currentPath + '/'}${property}`, currentObject[property]);
      if (result) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
}


document.write(
  generatePath("some_file.txt"), 
  '<br>', 
  generatePath("some_file2.txt"),
  '<br>',
  generatePath("up_file.txt"),
  '<br>',
  generatePath("no_file.txt")
);
```

Comment: When I look at it, it seems preatty close to what I've tried but it's simpler. Thanks so much for help! Now I understand how it works, finally...

Answer (score 0):

You can create recursive function for this using `for...in` loop that will store previous path elements in one array.

```js
const data = {
  "folder_name": {
    "another_folder": {
      "third_folder": {
        0: "some_file.txt",
        1: "another_file.png",
        2: "third_file.pdf"
      }
    }
  }
}

function generatePath(data, file) {
  let result

  (function getPath(obj, file, prev = []) {
    for (let i in obj) {

      if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
        getPath(obj[i], file, prev.concat(i).slice())
      }

      if (file == obj[i]) {
        result = prev.concat(obj[i]).join('/')
      }
    }
  })(data, file)

  return result;
}

console.log(generatePath(data, "third_file.pdf"))
console.log(generatePath(data, "some_file.txt"))
```